# How can I set the file name of the cucumber reports using net.masterthought plugin?

Tags: java, cucumber, test-report

I'm having issues setting up the file names from the masterthought plugin.

```
https://github.com/damianszczepanik/cucumber-reporting
```

TecStack from the project. java, junit, cucucumber, maven.

**For Feature File Name :**
This is the actual output: `report-feature_3444613442.html` 
This is the expected output: `report-feature_%FeatureName%_%Date%.html`

**For Tags File Name :**
This is the actual output: `report-tag-3444613442.html` 
This is the expected output: `report-tag-%taName%_%Date%.html`

I tried to debug where this naming was happening and in the jar file I found that in the class :

**src/main/java/net/masterthought/cucumber/json/Feature.java**

```java
    private String calculateReportFileName(int jsonFileNo) {
        // remove all characters that might not be valid file name
        String fileName = "report-feature_";

        // if there is only one report file or this is first one, don't add unnecessary numeration
        if (jsonFileNo > 0) {
            // add jsonFile index to the file name so if two the same features are reported
            // in two different JSON files then file name must be different
            fileName += jsonFileNo + "_";
        }

        fileName += Util.toValidFileName(uri);

        fileName += ".html";

        return fileName;
    }
```

Attached also a picture of the target folder with my actual results.

***What can I do to set up those names as I want.***

[image: Screenshot of the filenames]

Comment: What is this "3444613442" numbers is it random generated number or anything related to your project?

Comment: in function calculateReportFileName it is getting the hash value. it comes from the plugin library

Comment: Even I am facing this issue. how can we fixt it ?